# SuiteCRM switch sites, share login

Tags: php, authentication, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In a server I have 3 identical SuiteCRM (sugarCRM) installations, with the same users/passwords.

I only changed the domain:

1. localhost/moon,
2. localhost/sun,
3. localhost/cloud.

Now I want that when a user logs in one of them they can switch(redirect with alive session for that instance) to other sites without login again.

I imagine something like a combo select in each installation with the other two sites, so when the user selects another site is redirected there and logged in automatically, while the other session is destroyed.

I came from drupal and I thought to develop a custom module, but can anyone help me to start?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the same unique_key in all 3 config.php? A session would be allowing you to use all 3 installations with one login. Logging out and destroying sessions wouldn't be needed that way.